# Invoices status, Invoices statuses, Invoices' status or Invoices' statuses

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

According to [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/status), statuses is the plural of status. However, I am not sure here which one to use, my logic is statuses is more proper as each invoice has different status. But seems awkward word or unpopular at least. Further, I'm not sure if I have to use the possessive s or not.

**Example**

> Invoices statuses have been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's "invoice statuses", for the same reason it's "car horns" or "dog collars".